# Android run error by Gradle

Tags: ionic-framework, gradle

I'm having a serious problem with Android Gradle,
I created a project, and emulated by Android, this is what happened:

commands:

```
ionic start simple tabs
cd simple
ionic cordova emulate android
```

is this a normal response, am I doing something wrong here or not?

```
[19:02:48]  build dev finished in 13.28 s
> cordova run android

You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.
Android Studio project detected

ANDROID_HOME=G:\dl\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162
studio
[19:02:53]  lint finished in 4.70 s
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

:wrapper


BUILD SUCCESSFUL
 in 13s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Exception in thread "main"
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistName(PathAssembler.java:84)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistribution(PathAssembler.java:40)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:44)

        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
(node:2388) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistName(PathAssembler.java:84)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistribution(PathAssembler.java:40)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:44)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
(node:2388) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

[OK] Your app has been deployed.
     Did you know you can live-reload changes from your app with --livereload?
```

Comment: It looks like its throwing a couple exceptions during the deployment but it still successfully deploys. I wouldn't say its correct behavior.

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue? Any idea on the fix.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it by adding the variable of the Gradle address to the "path" of the system's variables, in my case: "C: \ Gradle \ gradle-4.9 \ bin"